# How to combine all 4 plots from plot(mod)? (R)

Tags: r, plot, model

I know about `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` but I would like to know if there is a quick way to make a 2x2 panel plot for the results you get when you make a model object (lm, aov etc.) and type `plot(mod)`?

Doesn't work if you run both those lines.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `par(mfrow = c(2, 2), oma = c(0, 0, 2, 0))` followed by
`plot(mod, which = 1:4)` ?

Comment: Thanks! Perfect!